# What does "screwing oneself lean and ugly" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "screwing oneself lean and ugly" mean? Sounds like something inappropriate, frankly. Wells's short story The Purple Pileus

> 'And you don't catch me **screwing myself lean and ugly**. Why didn't you marry a slavey?' I says, 'if you wanted one—instead of a respectable girl,' I says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole paragraph makes the meaning clear.

> “Said he wanted the money for his stock, or some such rubbish. Why, he
> wouldn’t have a woman in to help me once a week if it wasn’t for my
> standing out plucky. And the fusses he makes about money — comes to
> me, well, pretty near crying, with sheets of paper and figgers. ‘If
> only we can tide over this year,’ he says, ‘the business is bound to
> go.’ ‘If only we can tide over this year,’ I says; ‘then it’ll be, if
> only we can tide over next year. I know you,’ I says. ‘And you don’t
> catch me screwing myself lean and ugly. Why didn’t you marry a
> slavey?’ I says, ‘if you wanted one — instead of a respectable girl,’
> I says.”

The speaker is Mrs Coombes, and she is complaining about what she considers her husband's meanness with money. Slightly earlier she says that he refused to pay for a carriage at their wedding, and that her father had to. Now she says he wouldn't be paying for a maid to help her about the house if she had not insisted. She says that she told him that she had no intention of contorting herself ('screwing herself [up]') to perform menial domestic work, making herself thin and ugly. She considers herself 'respectable' and not one of the servant class. She asked Mr Coombes why he didn't marry a menial domestic servant girl (a 'slavey') if that is what he wanted.

> Screw (verb)
>
> to tighten the muscles of your face or part of your face into a
> particular expression, especially one of disapproval or pain:
> *He screwed his eyes tight shut against the bright light.*
> *The woman at the  breakfast table screwed her mouth into a grimace*.
>
> to twist and crush something, especially paper or cloth, roughly with
> your hands:
> *She screwed the bag up and threw it in the bin.*
> *He screwed the letter into a ball and flung it away.*

[Screw (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/screw)

Answer (score 0):

"To screw yourself" is a vulgar phrase meaning to mess up your life. Consider this excerpt from a [Vice article](https://www.vice.com/en/article/xdw3kn/playing-dead-excerpt):

> "I'd screwed myself financially, big time (for the second time!), and
> had nobody to blame but the creep in the mirror."

Now it's a lot more common to hear people say "screw yourself **over**" instead.

This is Mrs. Coombes complaining about the way her husband makes them live. She's saying that *he* is screwing himself, but that she wouldn't voluntarily live the way he does. The "lean and ugly" is qualifying the *way* the screwing is happening. You could make this sound more modern by adding

> And you don't catch me screwing myself ***over until I'm*** lean
> and ugly.

Comment: Wells was writing in 1896 in England. The 'screw yourself' expression came about 70 years later in America.

Comment: Ah, of course a brit would know the correct answer! I agree with you now